# Etymology of the term "filter"

Tags: general-topology, math-history, filters

According to [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28mathematics%29), filters were introduced in general topology by Henri Cartan in 1937.
I wonder why he called them filters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may not have been Cartan who named them. According to Michèle Audin, [‘Henri Cartan & André Weil du vingtième siècle et de la topologie’](http://www.math.polytechnique.fr/xups/xups12-01.pdf), p. $8$, the concept was originated at a meeting of Bourbaki in $1937$. After a morning of discussion most of the group went for a walk, but Cartan remained behind and came up with filters as a way of removing the countability restriction imposed by use of sequences. He came up with the idea, but not with the name (*La chose était inventée mais pas son nom.*)

I don’t know what the original motivation for the name was was, but it is certainly possible to see filters on a topological space as a way of filtering out points of a space. For example, if $\mathscr{N}(x)$ is the neighborhood filter of a point $x$ in a space $X$, each $N\in\mathscr{N}(x)$ can be thought of as filtering out the points of $X\setminus N$, keeping only those points that are ‘$N$-close’ to $x$. It does seem that the original motivation for filters was to get a general notion of convergence in topological spaces, and that’s precisely the setting in which this metaphor works best. Subsequently, of course, the notion was generalized and many other applications were found, but it wouldn’t surprise me if this or some similar metaphor were the reason for the name.

Comment: Thanks. I think you are probably right.

Comment: @MakotoKato: You’re welcome.

Comment: In some sources, it states that the theorem that every filter is contained in an ultrafilter was given by Tarski in 1930. As Engelking said, filters were introduced by Riesz in 1908. So when were ultrafilters introduced? Also what date is the filter base based on?

Comment: @MehmetOnat: My copy of Engelking does not say that filters were introduced by Riesz in 1908; it says that in 1907 and 1908 Riesz sketched an unsatisfactory notion of abstract topological space. I have seen Tarski’s 1930 paper *Une contribution à la théorie de la mesure*. In it he uses the axiom of choice to prove that every ideal can be extended to a maximal ideal, a result equivalent to the result that every filter can be extended to an ultrafilter, but he does not use the term *ideal* or the term *filter*; he talks about families of sets having certain properties, properties that we ...

Comment: ... now use to define ideals of sets. I have no idea when filter bases were first named, though I suspect that the term (*base de filtre* in French) goes back at least to Bourbaki. Similarly, I’ve no idea when the term *ultrafilter* was introduced for a maximal filter, but the concept of a maximal filter was available as soon as the concept of a filter was isolated and named.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott https://imgur.com/a/frDUq3A

Comment: @MehmetOnat: The parenthetical comment mentioning Riesz does not appear in my 1977 edition of Engelking; you must have a newer edition. In any case, I have tracked down [the Riesz paper in question](https://docplayer.org/50780054-F-riesz-stetigkeitsbegriff-und-abstrakte-mengenlehre.html). The concept of an abstract topological structure was still being formed, and Riesz sketches an approach that is essentially the notion of a [separated proximity space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximity_space), which is equivalent to the notion of a Tikhonov space. He isolates the notion of the ...

Comment: ... *fine proximity* on a space and approaches what is now called the Smirnov compactification of a proximity space, formed by adding as new points what are now called *clusters*. (See, e.g., [this PhD thesis](file:///home/brianmscott/Downloads/3d216ddb-e118-4c42-a033-89b64da57d2b.pdf) [PDF]. These clusters have a definition that is very similar to that of an ultrafilter and in special cases *are* ultrafilters, so it is fair to say that Riesz anticipated the notion of an ultrafilter, but what he had is technically a little different, and he seems not to have done anything with it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott By the way, the link above about Phd thesis is not working

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Riesz is also mentioned in the introduction to this article. https://www.jstor.org/stable/27642389

Comment: https://www.google.com.tr/books/edition/New_Infinitary_Mathematics/n_6LEAAAQBAJ?hl=tr&gbpv=1&dq=concepts+of+filter+and+ultrafilter+was+%C4%B1ntroduced+by+Riesz&pg=PA111&printsec=frontcover

Comment: The concept of an ultrafilter on a set was apparently enunciated first by F. Riesz [09], in an address that unfortunately did not receive at the time the attention it deserved.
https://www.google.com.tr/books/edition/The_Theory_of_Ultrafilters/L7_3CAAAQBAJ?hl=tr&gbpv=1&dq=The+concept+of+an+ultrafilter+on+a+set+was+apparently+enunciated+first+by+F.+Riesz+%5B09%5D,+in+an+address+that+unfortunately+did+not+receive+at+the+time+the+attention+it+deserved.&pg=PA59&printsec=frontcover

Comment: @MehmetOnat: Ah, I didn’t notice that the URL was to a downloaded copy. Try [this link](https://era.library.ualberta.ca/items/b76fcb9e-d479-4059-9949-5d28776848e2/download/3d216ddb-e118-4c42-a033-89b64da57d2b); clicking on it should download the PDF. That 2009 lecture is almost certainly the same as the 2008 paper, which is clearly the text of a talk, and if so, I disagree with Comfort and Negrepontis: what Riesz talked about is *very* similar to the notion of an ultrafilter but not quite identical.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott This link is lecture notes? I think this is your page. But i didnt find it. file:///home/brianmscott/Downloads/3d216ddb-e118-4c42-a033-89b64da57d2b.pdf

Comment: @MehmetOnat: It was a real URL, not the file address that you see there; I expected it to download a PDF file to *your* computer. Oh, well. Go [here](https://era.library.ualberta.ca/), and use the search box at the top of the page to search for *friedler mappings of proximity spaces*. Then download Friedler’s thesis, *Mappings of proximity spaces*.